# AWS code deploy after install whoami issues

Tags: laravel, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy

I'm migrating away from [Envoyer](https://envoyer.io/) to AWS code deploy to auto-deploy my Laravel app.

So I added this to my afterInstall script:

```
cd /project directory
composer install


if [ -f artisan ]
then
    php artisan migrate --force
fi

if [ -f artisan ]
then
    php artisan config:cache
    php artisan queue:restart
fi
```

But the deployment fails with this error

> MessageScript at specified location: scripts/after-install.sh run as
>   user user failed with exit code 1 Log TailLifecycleEvent -
>   AfterInstall Script - scripts/after-install.sh [stderr]No passwd entry
>   for user 'user'

which is weird. The AMI instance I've created already has the default user login as well as ubuntu as [sudoers](https://askubuntu.com/a/611607/131945):

```
grep -Po '^sudo.+:\K.*$' /etc/group
ubuntu,forge
```

So why is it asking for a password?

Answer (score 3):

I had to change the `runAs` section in the appspec file

```
in the script specified in "location".
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/after-install.sh
      runas: forge // used to be 'user'
```